# NodeJs: How to export an async value to another file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to access the result from an async function from one file in another file (say index.js).

**test.js**

```
const preMovie = async () => {
    const promiseTickets = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log("abcde");
        resolve('ticket is here')
    });

    let ticket = await promiseTickets;
    return ticket;
}

preMovie().then((m) => console.log(m));
```

**index.js**

```
//access the value of ticket here
```

My goal is to export the value inside ***ticket*** only when it has completed its task. I don't want to export an *undefined* value. I have tried my hand with different solutions, but either they are too complicated for me to understand or didn't blend with what I was looking for.

Comment: You can call the function from index.js file and await on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can export a Promise that resolves to `ticket`'s value:

```js
// test.js
const preMovie = async () => {
  const promiseTickets = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("abcde");
    resolve('ticket is here')
  });
  let ticket = await promiseTickets;
  return ticket;
}
const moviePromise = preMovie();
//export default moviePromise;



// main.js

//import moviePromise from './test.js';

moviePromise
  .then(ticket => console.log(ticket));
```

Uncomment the `import` and `export` statements when using them in your actual code, of course. Another option would be to export the function itself, calling it and calling `.then` on it, if there's a possibility of the function being needed to be called more than once, or if controlling its timing is important.

Comment: For some reason I'm getting this error.

import moviePromise from "./test.js";
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

I'm trying to check out a few solutions for this on SO right now.

Comment: Sounds like whatever module system you're using doesn't recognize `import`/`export` - just use whatever syntax is appropriate for your system.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution didn't work for me. I kept getting a message that the value is 'undefined'.

I was able to solve it via some other other method. However, thanks for the help!